# YAML - Escape \ in double quotes

Tags: symfony, phpunit, yaml, quotes, double-quotes

I'm having the following issue:

Classic symfony 2 project, phpunit 5.1.7.

In one yml config file I have something like this:

```
mobile_detect:
    service:
        mobile_detector: mobile_detect.mobile_detector.default
    twig_extension_class: "SunCat\MobileDetectBundle\Twig\Extension\MobileDetectExtension"
```

I run tests on my local machine (ubuntu) and everything works fine.

Then I deploy code (aws environment) and try to run tests. Everything fails with error:

```
"Unescaped character \M".
```

I see that in yaml double quotes parse strings so \M is indeed an undefined character. My question is... Why is it working file on local?

Also, the code works fine when I try to access normaly (through apache - browser call). Why is that also working well?

I guess the correct approach would be to replace all double quotes with single quotes but that would be really time consuming (can't do replace all beacause in some cases using them like that may have been intended). Is there any way to make tests on the tests machine to interpret yml as they do on the local machines?

Comment: how do you deploy the code on the aws environment? Check if could be an encoding settings on the transfer process

Comment: That was my first guess also, but encoding is fine, I also wrote the file manually on test env (same issue occured). I'm guessing is a phpunit thing because the code runs ok if normal requests are made.

Comment: About deploying (forgot to mentioned it) I am using elastic beanstalk for deploying. It basically creates an image with your code, rewrites the environment from a specific image, then copies the code image on it. After that it runs composer, and calls some custom scripts (that should not affect current issue).

Comment: While I don't know much about the software you are using, the alternative to using single-quotes is to leave them double-quotes and use two backslashes for the backslashes in your text.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way to make tests on the tests machine to interpret yml as they do on the local machines?

You are asking whether you can reproduce the *incorrect* behavior of the code on your local machine somewhere else. Depending on incorrect behavior is one of the worst things you can do; it tends to get fixed by software updates.

As you state yourself: The correct way is to fix you invalid YAML files. Be it by using single quotes or by escaping the backslashes with another backslash. There is no solution for keeping the current YAML files that is guaranteed to work when you update your software stack.

Comment: I'm sorry to point out (not downvoting). This is a valid point of view and I agree with it on principle. Reproducing incorrect behavior is one of worst things you can do - but is not always the case. The question was why this is happening. It would make a great comment but is not an answer to the actual question.